# How to change placeholder in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How do I change the data placeholder with select2?

So far I've tried this.

```
$("#city").select2({placeholder:"foo"});
```

And this...

```
$("#city").attr("data-placeholder","bar");
```

But neither works.

Comment: It should work.. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JZQ3Q/ Please repplicate your issue in this fiddle.

Comment: check my answer from here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964309/select2-control-place-holder-dynamically/73230257#73230257](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964309/select2-control-place-holder-dynamically/73230257#73230257)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that if I just set the attr e.g. `$("#city").attr('data-placeholder', 'bar')`, there is no effect. However, if I set the attr and then call `$("#city").select2()` with no arguments, then the placeholder updates.

e.g.

```
$("#city").attr("data-placeholder","bar");
$("#city").select2();
```

Comment: You could also just update the placeholder via `select2` after it's already been instantiated, without changing the element around (e.g. `$("#city").select2({ placeholder: "bar" });`).

Comment: Anyway, (re)applying `select2()` on the element will also loose any potential option previously set on this element through javascript

Answer (score 7):

For other people looking for an attribute solution to avoid changing JS code. I just had to look this up myself for a project, and it seems select2 just needs the attribute data-placeholder="".

```
<select id="city" data-placeholder="my placeholder"></select>
```

See more here: [select2 options reference](https://select2.github.io/options.html)

Comment: Mind telling me why the downvote? I just tried to be helpful and I do not see what I did wrong in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like this in the template (html) level. Just be sure to assign a blank (e.g. "") string on your first  tag.

```
<select id="city" data-placeholder="Select Anything">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

or we can simply add a data attribute for placeholder via javascript and it should happen before select2 gets initialized.

```
$('#city').data('placeholder','This is a placeholder');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wdonayre/687dtykd/72/)

Answer (score 3):

A bit more of a hack-y solution, but one that doesn't involve re-initiating the entire select element is to add the following extensions:

```
$.fn.getSelect2Placeholder = function () {
    var $select2Container = $(this).data('select2').$container;
    return $select2Container.find('.select2-selection__placeholder').text();
};
$.fn.setSelect2Placeholder = function (placeholder) {
    var $select2Container = $(this).data('select2').$container;
    return $select2Container.find('.select2-selection__placeholder').text(placeholder);
};
```

This allows for updating the placeholder by simply writing:

```
$('#the-id-of-your-select2-element').setSelect2Placeholder("Your placeholder text.");
```

[Source](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4653#issuecomment-358944224)

Comment: I found this useful, the only thing is if data is already selected then the `getSelect2Placeholder()` function will not be able to retrieve the placeholder value.

Answer (score 2):

A more direct way ..

```
$('#select2-' + $id + '-container').find('.select2-selection__placeholder').text('Your Text');
```

where `$id` is the `id` of the select element

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the html that your locator uses like this:

```
<select id="city" placeholder="my placeholder"></select>
```

Comment: Change to data-placeholder and it works with select2. 

`<select id="city" data-placeholder="my placeholder"></select>`

Answer (score 0):

For select2 version 4 I specified the placeholder text in js init code and then update it using `$select.select2{placeholder:"updated text..."}`

Answer (score 0):

The following script can be used:

```
$("#city").attr('placeholder', 'your text here' );
```