# select2 control place holder dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-5.8

I'm using select2 , i have many of them in my form

What i want is to control the placeholder for each of them dynamically to make the placeholder changed according to the `name` attribute for each select box

I tried the code

**HTML**

```
<select name="nationality_id" class="nationalities select2">
    <option></option>
    @foreach ($nationalities as $nationality)
       <option value="{{ $nationality->id }}">
       {{ $nationality->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".select2").each(function(){
     var attr = $(this).attr('name');
     $(this).select2({
     placeholder: "{{ __('site." + attr + "')}}"
   })
});
```

but the result in the select box like this

```
site.&quot; + attr + &quot;
```

how to do that !!?

Comment: Is your `jquery` in a `<script>` element in a `.blade.php`? Or is it in a `.js` file? Cause you can't use `{{ }}` (blade templating) functions in a `.js` file, nor can you mix `js` elements (like `attr`) into `php` like that.

Comment: it is in a <script> element in a .blade.php

Comment: That's good. However, you can't use `"{{ __('site." + attr + "') }}"` since `attr` is a `js` variable.

Comment: got it .. so is there any way to do what i want ? .. i don't want to repeat the code many times for just the place holder

Answer (score 0):

**Placeholder only works when there is an empty option**.
Read the discussion here.

[Github discussion](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3553)

I hope this helps.